# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './helpers/llamadas' al importarlo en otro archivo js en electron.js cuando el modulo esta exportado

Tags: javascript, nodejs, electron

Tengo una aplicacion hecha en electron js y estoy creando archivos que me sirvan como modulos para poder llamar funciones que me serviran en todo el proyecto, el problema es que al importarlo me dice que no encuentra dicho modulo aun que si exista, le adjunto captura

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No me cuadra de verdad porque anteriormente había utilizado el mismo método en otro proyecto y funcionaba, le agregue un pequeño servidor con express para que interactue con la bd.

Dejo el link del repo https://github.com/Izaack-B97/fast-food

Si pueden ayudarme se los agradeceria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se demasiado de Electron, pero creo que es porque la ruta tiene que ser relativa a donde esta el archivo html, es decir:

```
const { getToServer } = require("./js/helpers/llamadas");
```

Creo que así ya lo encuentra

Comment: Tienes razón, si me funciono, muchas gracias man !